# Calculate the sum of the first N terms of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n=a_{n-1}\displaystyle \frac{n+1}{n}$ if $n > 1$

$a_n=1$ if $n=1$

I'm not too sure where to start here. This is part of a review for a class and I can't really seem to remember what we're reviewing. The first 5 values are...

$a_1 = 1,a_2=1.5,a_3=2,a_4=2.5,a_5=3$

Sums of these to each point....

$a_1=1, a_2=2.5, a_3=4.5, a_4=7, a_5=10$

It doesn't seem like it should be too tricky to figure out how to get a formula for a sum of the first N terms, since each term seems to just increase by 0.5 every team, I just haven't done this for a while and am a little rusty. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know how to sum an [Arithmetic Progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)?

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Answer seems to be $n/2(a_1 + a_{n})$

Comment: @Hoser:  correct, but it is better to write $n(a_1+a_n)/2$ so it is obvious that the $(a_1+a_n)$ is in the numerator.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: The trick is to show that $a_i$ is an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 2):

Just to give a complete answer, the pattern for each term appears to be $a_n=\frac{n}{2}+\frac12$

To prove it, this correctly gives $a_1=1$ and $a_{n-1}\frac{n+1}{n}= \left(\frac{n-1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{n+1}{n}=\frac{n+1}{2}=\frac{n}{2}+\frac12$ so the hypothesis is true by induction

As you say, the sum of the first $n$ terms is $\frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$, since this is an arithmetic progression.  This is $\frac{n\left(1+\frac{n}{2}+\frac12\right)}{2} = \frac{n\left(n+3\right)}{4}$ and for example gives the sum of the first five terms as $\frac{5 \times 8}{4} = 10$ as you found